# Как реализовать собственные методы обработки REST API в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, rest

После прочтения документации и пробы `yii\rest\ActiveController` встал вопрос об организации собственных методов, которые не просто выдают данные или заносят их, но и в процессе вызывают какую-то бизнес логику. Как это реализовать?

На текущий момент есть классическая таблица `user` и ее модель, где есть поля `id, name, age`. Как сделать, например, при обращении к /user/1 какую-то свою бизнес логику? Или ля этого надо делать обычные контроллеры?

Comment: Так а чем не устраивают  __обычные контроллеры__?

Comment: @u_mulder устраивают. Просто тогда не вижу смысла в yii rest, если туда нельзя никак свою бизнес логику воткнуть

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин вся бизнес логика всегда делается не зависимо от каких либо фреймворков. Фреймворки лишь какая-то удобная оболочка над общими операциями, методами, подходами.......rest - всего лишь стиль, подход к организации взаимодействия в сети.... РЕСТу вообще плевать что на фреймворки, что на бизнес логики, он о них не знает ничего.......yii rest в целом ничем не отличается от простого yii, совершенно абсолютно, только предоставляя немного более удобные пути работы с rest (например правила выстраивания данных в модели) и частично преднастроенные (типа отдачи в json, ендпойнтов и т.д.).

Comment: Т.е. yii rest - это всё тот же yii, только "подкрученный" под конкретный подход и работу в этом направлении

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился следующим образом:

1. Создали модуль api, в котором сделали контроллеры, модели и прочее
2. Контроллеры наследуем от `yii\rest\Controller`
3. В маршрутизации пишем:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => UrlRule::class,
            'controller' => [
                'api/<controller>',
            ],
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'GET api/<controller>/based' => 'api/<controller>/based'
            ],
            'pluralize' => false, // Исключает множественное число английской формы
        ],

        '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Тут в `extraPatterns` задаем шаблоны для кастомных методов.